# Scroll down listbox automatically

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm using Matlab R2018a where there is no `scroll` function. I just need to scroll down the listbox as items are added (dynamically).

I found this solution on Google but is not working for me.

```
handles.slider.Max = length(handles.listbox.String);
handles.slider.Value = handles.slider.Max;
```

Is there any other solution?

Comment: What's a `listbox`? Could you please [edit] the question to contain more information on the problem and preferably a [mcve] which we can run ourselves?

Comment: What does “is not working for me” mean? Error message? No change? How does `handles.slider` relate to your listbox?

Comment: The listbox property `ListboxTop` should be able to control which item is the one displayed at the top. This does not seem to work for me, though.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the `ListboxTop` property to have an effect, the UI has to be redrawn (using `drawnow`) after adding the items to the listbox.

Example, using GUIDE with one listbox tagged as `listbox1`:

In the GUI's `OpeningFcn`, write

```
handles.t = timer('BusyMode', 'drop', 'ExecutionMode',...
'fixedRate', 'StartDelay', 4, 'Period', 4.0, 'TimerFcn', {@addItem, hObject});
handles.ctr = 0;
handles.t.start();
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

At the end, add

```
function addItem(hObject, EventData, parentO)

handles = guidata(parentO);
handles.ctr = handles.ctr + 1;
handles.listbox1.String{end+1} = sprintf('Item %i', handles.ctr);
drawnow
handles.listbox1.ListboxTop = numel(handles.listbox1.String) ;
guidata(parentO, handles);
```

Note that when uncommenting the `drawnow` line, the listbox will always jump to the selected item (the first one by default).